# How to concatenate cols under special rules?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to select concatenated string, max 255 char. Original query, without shortenings, was:

```sql
SELECT
  b.title 
      ||
    CASE 
      WHEN b.subtitle != '' THEN '. ' || b.subtitle
      ELSE ''
    END
      ||
    CASE 
      WHEN b.cover = 'paperback' THEN ' P'
      WHEN b.cover = 'hardcover' THEN ' K'
      WHEN b.cover = 'spiral' THEN ' S'
      ELSE ''
    END
      ||
    CASE 
      WHEN b.year > 0 THEN ' ' || b.year
      ELSE ''
    END
      ||
    CASE 
      WHEN b.volume > 0 THEN ' ' || b.volume || '. osa'
      ELSE ''
    END
      ||
    CASE 
      WHEN p.name != '' THEN ' ' || p.name
      ELSE ''
    END
    AS name
  FROM table b
    JOIN table_p p
      ON b.id = p.foreign_id;
```

**Rule**: concatenated string may be up to 255 chars

Prioritized fields:

- `b.title` (text, up to 250 chars),
- `b.cover` (2 chars),
- `b.year` (4 char + space = 5),
- `b.volume` (int<100 + additional string '. osa' = 7-8 chars).

Less important:

- `b.subtitle` (text, up to 250 chars),
- `p.name` (text, up to 150 chars )

All fields besides b.title may absent/be empty.

One approach I can think of: because three short mandatory fields (`cover`, `year`, `volume`) may be max 15 chars, everything other could be max 240 chars. Because `p.name` is not so important, I could concatenate and cut afterwards, if needed. So main objective with this approach: `b.title` + `b.subtitle` must fit into 240 chars. Looks like that:

```sql
SELECT
  SUBSTR(  
    SUBSTR( b.title 
        ||
      CASE 
        WHEN b.subtitle != '' THEN '. ' || b.subtitle
        ELSE ''
      END, 
    0, 240 )
        ||
      CASE 
        WHEN b.cover = 'paperback' THEN ' P'
        WHEN b.cover = 'hardcover' THEN ' K'
        WHEN b.cover = 'spiral' THEN ' S'
        ELSE ''
      END
        ||
      CASE 
        WHEN b.year > 0 THEN ' ' || b.year
        ELSE ''
      END
        ||
      CASE 
        WHEN b.volume > 0 THEN ' ' || b.volume || '. osa'
        ELSE ''
      END
        ||
      CASE 
        WHEN p.name != '' THEN ' ' || p.name
        ELSE ''
      END,
  0, 255 )  AS name
  FROM table b
    JOIN table_p p
      ON b.id = p.foreign_id;
```

This approach is Ok-ish.

My question: is there better way to control every aspect of such concatenation?

I am using Postgresql 9.6

Comment: Do you really need the `ELSE ''` you have in many places? Maybe not important but if you can skip them it would mean less code.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson the reasoning was "safe defaults", nothing fundamental.